# Found a lot of function names in firmware dump. Is it possible to recreate original code?

Tags: firmware

I'm using IDA PRO 5.0 Free to analyze firmware from a camcorder (mn103 processor). I'm a complete newbie in reverse engineering so it's hard for me to learn how it works only using assembly code. I found out, there are a lot of original function names left in the dump:
[image]

Is it possible to get C code with original function names from this? I don't have Hex Rays decompiler tho.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. What you're seeing is mostly a bunch of debug strings that were left in. The code itself is still machine language and there's no way to directly translate that back into the original. Your best option is a decompiler like Hex-Rays, but that will still only give an approximation.